# Evaluating streaks

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let's define two games: in the game $G_A$ the player wins $20€$ with a probability of the $20\%$, otherwise he losses $2€$. In the game $G_B$ the player wins $2€$ with a probability of $80\%$, otherwise losses $1€$.

It is easy to see that playing successively game $G_A$ is more convenient for the player in terms of the Expected Value, since $EV_{G_A} = 20\cdot0.2 - 2\cdot0.8 = 2.4$ and $EV_{G_B} = 2\cdot0.8-1\cdot0.2 = 1.4$.

However, I would like to have information about the streaks when playing both games. For instance:

- If the initial budget is $10€$, which is the probability of achieving $0€$ when playing consecutively game $G_A$ or $G_B$?.
- Can I say that, after $100$ rounds playing $G_A$, the budget will be certain number $M \pm v$, with a probability $P$? And in that case, how can I obtain $M$, $v$ and $P$?
- Is it possible to obtain a strategy which alternates both games, in order to maximize the EV but somehow limiting the expected maximum losses?

The proposed games are just examples. Getting the name of the field which study this stuff will be enough: I just need a start point.

Comment: I believe $EV_{G_B}=2\times .8 - 1 \times .2$?

Comment: Note:  the first problem falls under the heading of the [Gambler's Ruin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin) and has been extensively written about.  The second can be handled similarly, though I think most people would simply simulate the process (not a bad way to handle the first problem either).  For the third I think you need to specify more (maybe you stop if you reach some level or after some set number of moves) and you need to specify a Utility function (how do you evaluate a trade off in yield against reduced risk?)

Comment: Thanks, all your comments were very useful. (PS: error corrected!)

Comment: Also, look at 'negative binomial distribution'.